# Get XML nodes from SQL Server column as comma-separated list

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have a data stored in a xml column and need a comma-separated list of child nodes. Using script below, I can only get "A B C". Please help me get "A,B,C" using xquery (Simple replace of space with comma does not help because we have data with spaces inside).

```
create table Temp12345 (col1 xml)
go

insert into Temp12345 (col1)
values('<fd><field i="22"><v>A</v><v>B</v><v>C</v></field></fd>')
go

select col1.value('(/fd/field[@i=22])[1] ', 'NVarchar(Max)') 
from Temp12345
go

drop table Temp12345
go
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT 
              ',' + fd.v.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
           FROM 
              Temp12345
           CROSS APPLY
              col1.nodes('/fd/field/v') AS fd(v)
           FOR XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '')
```

This gives me `A,B,C` - does it work for you, too?

Comment: +1 for a working answer. Out of curiosity, I see you're using CROSS APPLY. I have done something similar with a CTE. Is there any significant advantage to either approach?

Comment: @IanC: not sure - would have to see your CTE :-) That's just the way I know I can "shred" a list of XML nodes into a "pseudo-table" of row, to grab individual bits and pieces from it.

Comment: @marc not the same application, but it queries the XML in a similar way: WITH t AS (
   SELECT x.node.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS RankItem, 
     x.node.value('(.)', 'float') AS Value
   FROM @xml.nodes('/data/*') AS x(node)  -- select *direct* children of the root 'data' node
  )
  SELECT @OutOfBounds = Count(t.RankItem)
  FROM t INNER JOIN [int].RankItems AS ri ON ri.RankItem = t.RankItem
  WHERE (t.Value < ri.[Min] OR t.Value > ri.[Max])

Comment: It does a join onto a lookup table to ensure values are within range, and counts how many are out of range.

Comment: @IanC: works great on a single XML variable - but how are you going to extend that to include several rows which each have a XML column?? That's where the `CROSS APPLY` really shines...

Comment: @Marc the input XML, for my use case, will always be in the format of 1 column, several rows. I'm not having any problems with 10 rows. Each is correctly evaluated. However, I am interested if CROSS APPLY is a better approach.

Comment: @IanC: but then you're somehow looping over your 10 rows, and calling your CTE for each entry, right?? Cross Apply works against any number of rows at once

Comment: @Marc my understanding of what I pasted is the CTE is a table, which is the result of a 1-time conversion of the XML, and I then process against this table by joining it to a reference table and evaluating the results. I don't see why it would be looping.

Comment: @Marc per http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/, it seems to me that I am understanding this correctly. There is no recursion here.

Answer (score 0):

In a full complain XQuery processor you could use just:

```
(/fd/field[@i=22])[1]/string-join(*,',')
```

Comment: Doesn't work in SQL Server though. It gives the error `The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.`

Comment: @Martin: Yes, but not even `fn:string-join()` is supported

Comment: It supports `concat` but I couldn't figure out any useful way of using it. `'concat((/fd/field[@i=22])[1],'','')'` just gives `ABC,`

Comment: @Martin: Each argument of `fn:concat()` function should be an instance of `xs:string` data type. So, you can't use sequence. That only leaves a "static" solution like `concat(v[1],',',v[2],',',v[3])`. I have no SQL Server instance to test, so I don't know how it deals with sequence responso like `for $item in (/fd/field[@i=22])[1]/* return if ($item/following-sibling::node()[1]) then concat($item,',') else string($item)`

Comment: Here's a list of MS SQL supported XQuery functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx