# The endless debate: atomic inserts, locking, & transactions in SQL Server. It ends here

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concurrency, locking

**Edit:** My question is, "Why does my first code example work?" Please read on...

**Edit1:** There is no doubt that a unique constraint is the correct way to ensure duplicates don't happen. This is a given. However, sometime we need to know that we're attempting a duplicate entry. Further, this post goes beyond merely handling duplicates.

This is potentially a repeat of probably over 100 questions on SO. I've read an endless array of confusions and contradictions about the simple questions of atomic updates, locks, and concurrency.

I see that blogs and experts disagree widely on these points. Here I provide test code based on the various solutions people have advised, indicate the results, state my views, and invite your comment.

Context: I'm running SQL Server 2008 Express SP2.

I created the following test table:

```
create table dbo.Temp (Col int)
```

The table deliberately has no constraints on it as we want to test the SQL code ideas, not constraints.

I ran the following concurrently in 2 and then 3 query windows:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0

while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    update dbo.temp set Col = (SELECT Col from dbo.Temp) + 1
end
```

I did not use any explicit locking, as can be seen. All DB settings are default. I checked the value of Col and it was the desired number: 25,000. Nothing missed.

Since SQL Server is ACID, the "A" tells us that a single statement is executed atomically. Therefore, based on the above, we could agree with those who say that locks are not needed for a simple update as above.

Next, I ran the following concurrently in 3 query windows:

```
while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    insert into dbo.temp select @i where not exists
      (select 1 from dbo.temp where Col = @i)
end
```

The results were **not** correct, despite the fact this is one statement. There were missing values, duplicate values, and > 5k rows.

Next, I ran the following popular solution concurrently in 3 query windows:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0

while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    insert into dbo.temp select @i where not exists 
      (select 1 from dbo.temp with (updlock) where Col = @i)
end
```

The results were **not correct**. There were missing values, duplicate values, and > 5k rows.

Next, for those who have doubts that SQL Server implicitly wraps single statements in a transaction (aka "A" in ACID):

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0

while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    begin tran
    insert into dbo.temp select @i where not exists 
      (select 1 from dbo.temp with (updlock) where Col = @i)
    commit tran
end
```

Same **incorrect** results.

Next, I ran the following concurrently in 3 query windows:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0

while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    insert into dbo.temp select @i where not exists 
      (select 1 from dbo.temp with (XLOCK, ROWLOCK) where Col = @i)
end
```

This **worked**. 5k unique values only.

Next, the following in 3 windows:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0

while @i < 5000 begin
    set @i = @i + 1
    merge dbo.temp as t
    using (select @i) as test (Col)
    ON (t.Col = test.Col)
    when not matched then
        insert values (@i);
end
```

This **worked**. 5k unique values only.

My conclusions are:

1. SQL Server is atomic for *single SQL operations*, not *groups of operations that appear as one statement*.
2. UPDLOCK is *not* effective, as shown and as suggested by many, at providing the required locking needed to guarantee update integrity in a contentious environment.
3. From a locking perspective, only XLOCK guarantees *concurrency integrity* and *atomicity in multi-statement operations as shown*.
4. The MERGE command is a single command, and therefore is atomic.

Please test this for yourself.

Now, can someone explain to me why my first example worked? :-)

Comment: The best solution here would be to use a INT IDENTITY to let SQL Server handle the uniqueness of the INT column....... but that's a well know fact, nothing new here, really.....

Comment: Of course. I always use indexes and allow indexes to genuinely guarantee uniqueness. However, obviously sometimes we need to know a row exists and process accordingly, in which case we have to test. Do you have any idea why e.g. #1 works?

Comment: @Marc, as a side note, I got into a conversation with you on another post, but we never concluded. It was about a CTE I wrote. You indicated it was recursive, but I couldn't see why. Since you def. know your stuff, I have attention on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379039/get-xml-nodes-from-sql-server-column-as-comma-separated-list/4379166#4379166

Comment: @Mrac thanks - email sent :-)

Comment: Odd that a 3-time favorited question is closed as "not a question".

Comment: @IanC: Grumpy moderators were over-tired and didn't have their juice.

Comment: @IanBoyd I believe you're correct.

Comment: I don't know how to ask this in the correct form but is there a way I can use this 'not a real question' to reference other 'real questions' that I might have? It is a great article that can be expounded on and continues to provide insight in the year 2018.