# How can I query a SQL Server XML column and return all values for a specific node?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

I have the following XML in a XML column in SQL Server.

```
  <qualifiers>
    <qualifier>
      <key>111</key>
      <message>a match was not found</message>
    </qualifier>
    <qualifier>
      <key>222</key>
      <message>a match was found</message>
    </qualifier>
    <qualifier>
      <key>333</key>
      <message>error</message>
    </qualifier>
  </qualifiers>
```

How can I write TSQL to return all the values in qualifiers/qualifier/message in a comma delimited string?  My goal is to have the query return the values from the XML in a single column for each row.

The results should look like this:

```
"a match was not found, a match was found, error"
```

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379039/get-xml-nodes-from-sql-server-column-as-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6df1/2) for the same: Solution as per @xQbert suggested

```
create table Temp (col1 xml)
go

insert into Temp (col1)
values('<qualifiers>
    <qualifier>
      <key>111</key>
      <message>a match was not found</message>
    </qualifier>
    <qualifier>
      <key>222</key>
      <message>a match was found</message>
    </qualifier>
    <qualifier>
      <key>333</key>
      <message>error</message>
    </qualifier>
  </qualifiers>')
go

SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT 
              ',' + fd.v.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
           FROM 
              Temp
           CROSS APPLY
              col1.nodes('/qualifiers/qualifier/message') AS fd(v)
           FOR XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is what you are looking for :
-- it is from the LINK : 
-- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>White</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color1,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color2,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color3,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]/@Special','varchar(10)')+' '+
+a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color4,
a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color5[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color5,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits2[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits2,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits3[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits3,
a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits4[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits4
FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b)
```