# SQL Server retrieve all values

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes, cross-apply

I have a table, let's call it `TBL`, with a column of type `XML`.

The `XML` column (called `xml` here) is of the format:

```
<START xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="87jjhanM">
    <Header xmlns="">
    ...
    </Header>
    <Fetch xmlns="">
    .....
    </Fetch>
    <Send xmlns="">
        <Supplier>
            <Deals>
                <Deal>
                   <Field1> </Field1>
                   <Field2> </Field2>
                </Deal>
            </Deals>
        </Supplier>
        <Supplier>
            <Deals>
                <Deal>
                   <Field1> </Field1>
                   <Field2> </Field2>
                </Deal>
            </Deals>
        </Supplier>
    </Send>
</START>
```

Notice that each XML document can have multiple `<Supplier>` tags. What I am interested in, is getting the values of `Field1` and `Field2`.

From reading e.g [How can I query a SQL Server XML column and return all values for a specific node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626518/how-can-i-query-a-sql-server-xml-column-and-return-all-values-for-a-specific-nod) and [Getting multiple records from xml column with value() in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393250/getting-multiple-records-from-xml-column-with-value-in-sql-server) it seems that I should be using some sort of cross apply.

I just can't seem to make it work. With `value()`, I am perfectly capable of getting the first instance found, but with `nodes()` I fail miserably (SQL Server).

My blatant rip-off attempt (here only for Field1) for getting all the Field1 values are:

```
SELECT  
    xml.value('(/Supplier/Deals/Deal/Field1[1])[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS A
FROM    
    TBL
CROSS APPLY 
    xml.nodes('/Start/Send') x(A);
```

which, as far as I understand, simply looks for the first value `/Supplier/Deals/Deal/Field1` under each `/Start/Send/`, but it does not work - it simply returns 0 rows affected (I know the specific structure exist in the XML files I should say).

I am sure this is quite easy, but I just can't wrap my head around why the above does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few things wrong that are probably not directly relevant to your question: XML is case-sensitive (so `START`, not `Start`), the outer element is in a namespace (`87jjhanM`) and so requires a `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, that sort of thing. But assuming we sort all that out:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('87jjhanM' AS n)
SELECT 
    A.value('Field1[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Field1, 
    A.value('Field2[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Field2
FROM    TBL
CROSS APPLY [xml].nodes('/n:START/Send/Supplier/Deals/Deal') x(A);
```

The `CROSS APPLY` should ideally be done on the lowest repeating element we're interested in (`Deal` in this case) to make the `value` queries as simple as possible, but this is not a hard requirement.

If instead you wanted all values in `Field1` and `Field2`, but you don't care what field they're actually in, you could match by name:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('87jjhanM' AS n)
SELECT 
    A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Field]
FROM    TBL
CROSS APPLY [xml].nodes('/n:START/Send/Supplier/Deals/Deal/*[local-name()="Field1" or local-name()="Field2"]') x(A);
```

If you wanted to, say, get everything in every element starting with `Field`... well then things get a *lot* more annoying, but fortunately you said you know the structure of the XML involved, so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to shorten and clean this for brevety, that's good. But - at least I think so - you did a bit to much...

Jeroen Mostert has pointed already to the casing ("START"!="Start") and the namespaces. There is a (rather odd) defualt namespace in the first line, and some namespaces you do not use at all.

The repeating `xmlns=""` within your XML are quite dangerous. This is probably created by a `T-SQL` command with `FOR XML` and sub-selects. The point is: This is not *just something silly to ignore*, but you are defining a **new default namespace** for the inner elements. That's why I used the namespace wildcard `*:` and omitted the namespace declaration.

I added some additional elements to each level and assumed, that there can be `1:n` `<Supplier>` and `1:n` `<Deal>` nodes below `<Deals>` (at least the naming points to this). You can use two levels of `OUTER / CROSS APPLY` for this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTBL TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, TheXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTBL VALUES
(N'<START xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="87jjhanM">
   <Header xmlns="">
      <SomeNodeWithinHeader SomeValue="blah"/>
   </Header>
 <Fetch xmlns="">
      <SomeNodeWithinFetch SomeValue="blubb"/>
 </Fetch>
 <Send xmlns="">
   <Supplier>
     <SupplierRelatedData value="Sup1"/>
     <Deals>
       <Deal>
         <Field1>A1</Field1>
         <Field2>A2</Field2>
       </Deal>
       <Deal>
         <Field1>A3</Field1>
         <Field2>A4</Field2>
       </Deal>
     </Deals>
   </Supplier>
   <Supplier>
     <SupplierRelatedData value="Sup2"/>
     <Deals>
       <Deal>
         <Field1>B1</Field1>
         <Field2>B2</Field2>
       </Deal>
     </Deals>
   </Supplier>
 </Send>
 </START>');

 SELECT m.TheXml.value(N'(/*:START/Header/SomeNodeWithinHeader/@SomeValue)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') ValueWithinHeader
       ,m.TheXml.value(N'(/*:START/Fetch/SomeNodeWithinFetch/@SomeValue)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') ValueWithinFetch
       ,sup.value(N'(SupplierRelatedData/@value)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') SupplierRelatedData
       ,deal.value(N'(Field1/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Field1
       ,deal.value(N'(Field2/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Field2
 FROM @mockupTBL AS m
 OUTER APPLY m.TheXml.nodes(N'/*:START/Send/Supplier') AS A(sup)
 OUTER APPLY A.sup.nodes(N'Deals/Deal') AS B(deal)
```

The result

```
blah    blubb   Sup1    A1  A2
blah    blubb   Sup1    A3  A4
blah    blubb   Sup2    B1  B2
```